# Postgres AUTOCOMMIT is ON on 2 databases, but "there is no transaction in progress" output on 1 database

Tags: postgresql, transactions, autocommit

I have a postgres db in a few different environments (i.e. dev, qa, prod).

Both databases have AUTOCOMMIT ON (checked in psql using \echo :AUTOCOMMIT command)

My question one of my databases that should have identical settings is outputting in the output window of my DB client IDE (Dbeaver)

```
there is no transaction in progress
```

....If I do a random `commit;` in the query editor. However, if I do this same `commit;` in my other db that should same settings, nothing is output in the Window.

Is there a specific settings that controls this output message? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the client in question psql o DBeaver? Chose one and tag that.

Comment: In `psql` `\echo :AUTOCOMMIT ` shows what `psql` is set to not the database. The server is always in autocommit unless you explicitly start a transaction, see [BEGIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-begin.html). Best guess is that there is setting in your client that is controlling this.

Comment: there is an article that seems to have some good explanation you might be able to work out the issue from : https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/disabling-autocommit-in-postgresql-can-damage-your-health/

Answer (score -1):

DBeaver has a button somewhere in the middle of the button bar to disable autocommit. This is activated in one of the cases and deactivated in the other. PostgreSQL itself has no way to disable autocommit, this is always done on the client side (like with `\set AUTOCOMMIT off` in `psql`). Changing the setting in one client won't change the setting in another client.

I highly [recommend that you keep autocommit enabled everywhere](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/disabling-autocommit-in-postgresql-can-damage-your-health/) to avoid breaking your database with interactive sessions that inadvertently keep transactions open.